# Equivalent syntax to xargs --for use on mac os

Tags: linux, xargs, macos

Team,

I have xargs that works fine on ubuntu but i can't run same command on mac. any hint please? am searching but no luck yet

ubuntu linux

```
cat test.log | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo $1' --
```

output

```
try
test
me
```

mac

```
cat test.log | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo $1' --
```

```
xargs: illegal option -- l
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
```

Comment: works post it as answer please. it worked. thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A manpage for GNU `xargs` writes,

> **`-l[max-lines]`**, **`--max-lines[=max-lines]`** Synonym for the `-L` option. [...] The `-l` option is deprecated since the POSIX standard specifies `-L` instead.

and

> **`-L max-lines`** Use at most `max-lines` nonblank input lines per command line. [...]

From this we can read that `-l1` can be directly and more correctly replaced with `-L1`.